# Convergence of a sequence that satisfies a recurrence relation in Apery's theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to prove the assertion in theorem 1 of [this](http://www.numdam.org/article/STNG_1977-1978__6__A6_0.pdf) paper saying that $a_n \sim A \alpha^n n^{-3/2}$ for a certain positive constant $A$.

I know that $a_n$ satisfies the relation

$$a_{n+2} +p_1(n) b_{n+1} + p_2(n)b_n=0$$

where $p_1(n) \longrightarrow -34$ and $p_2(n)\longrightarrow 1$.

As the roots of $x^2-34x+1$ are $17 \pm 12\sqrt2$ and $a_n$ is strictly increasing, by Poincaré's theorem on linear difference equations, we have that if we denote $\alpha=17 + 12\sqrt2$ as in the paper,

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow+\infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \alpha$$

Now, as $b_n >0$ from the previous limit we have that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow+\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \alpha$$

Now, from this last limit I was trying to prove that  the sequence

$$A_n=\dfrac{a_n}{\alpha^n n ^{-3/2}}$$

converges to a positive real value, and from that we will be done, but I'm not able to conclude the convergence.

I also know that we can express $a_n$ as

$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^2 {n+k \choose k}^2$$

but I don't know if that helps to solve my question.

I would really apreciate any help on how to prove the convergence.

Comment: This is about [OEIS sequence A005259](https://oeis.org/A005259). A formula entry states: "a(n) ~ (1+sqrt(2))^(4*n+2)/(2^(9/4)*Pi^(3/2)*n^(3/2)). - Vaclav Kotesovec, Nov 01 2012".

Comment: @Somos That's exactly what I want to prove.